# How to compile NodeJS on a D-Link DNS 325 with fun_plug 0.5 installed?

Tags: linux, node.js, compiler-errors, arm, uclibc

I am trying to compile Node on my NAS device, but I get this error, and I don't really know how to make this work:

```
/node-v0.6.6/deps/v8/src/arm/constants-arm.h:33:2: error: #error ARM EABI support is 

required.
scons: *** [obj/release/accessors.o] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
Waf: Leaving directory `/ffp/home/root/node-v0.6.6/out'
Build failed:  -> task failed (err #2): 
    {task: libv8.a SConstruct -> libv8.a}
```

Did someone actually manage do get Node to compile on a D-Link NAS? Does someone know of any official guides to doing this or where should I ask for help?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 5):

DNS320, Fonzplug, NodeJS, Funplug, (DNS323, my original target) also appears to apply to sheeva plug!!.

(as a matter of interest 323 takes about 7.5 hours to compile, whilst 320 takes 1hr, 3 minutes)

(also compile on 1G8 Intel Linux (Debian) take about 15 minutes)

========================
NOTE: on fonz plug - you need the following installed:

- binutils
- List item
- kernel-headers
- pkg-config
- uclibc
- gcc
- make
- gettext
- patch
- bison
- flex
- autoconf
- automake

=======================
then you can:

```
exported TMPDIR=/ffp/tmp        (need this to put tmp files on HD not in memory!)

export CC='gcc -march=armv5t -mfloat-abi=softfp -fno-tree-sink -O0'
export CCFLAGS='-march=armv5t -mfloat-abi=softfp -fno-tree-sink -O0'
export CXX='g++ -march=armv5t -mfloat-abi=softfp -fno-tree-sink -O0'
export GCC='-march=armv5t -mfloat-abi=softfp -fno-tree-sink -O0'

./configure --prefix=/ffp --without-snapshot
......
make
.............
make install
```

---

### Notes:

I have had experience with NodeJS 0.4.9 - so I have kept using it - read on as to why!!

actually compiles without error!!
BUT!

### when run - Illegal instruction - pops up

this appears to be because V8 is EXPECTED to be compiled on a host machine that is NOT an arm!!

see below for references I've found: (It has taken me 6 months to find all these)
Someone, somewhere has decided that running on ARM is an embedded environment, therefore you won't ever compile on it!!

Can someone with authority fix this!!!!!!!!

The fact that I can get a clean compile, says it can work, but at least V8 doesn't want us too????

original instructions:
    https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installation

What else I have found:

```
http://code.google.com/p/v8/wiki/CrossCompilingForARM
http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=914
http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=1632&q=vfp%20off&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20HW%20OS%20Area%20Stars
https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/1566
http://fastr.github.com/articles/Node.js-on-OpenEmbedded.html
http://freebsd.1045724.n5.nabble.com/problems-with-cvsup-on-FreeBSD-9-snapshot-201101-td4491053.html
http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=1446
http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dai0133c/index.html
http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.qrc0007e/QRC0007_VFP.pdf
https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/1386
https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/2131
```

and from this article, the minimum installs of fonz stuff that needs to be pre-installed:

```
http://www.shadowandy.net/2008/08/adding-compiling-capabilities-to-your-dns-323.htm
```

DNS323 - wiki site (new one??!!)

```
http://dns323.kood.org/dns-320
http://tsd.dlink.com.tw/downloads2008detail.asp (open source for dlink find dns then 320 - or 323 etc)
```

compiler options:

```
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html
```

debugging options:
    http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html

Interest:

```
http://itrs.tw/wiki/Code_Sourcery_G%2B%2B_Lite
http://pandorawiki.org/Floating_Point_Optimization
http://wiki.debian.org/ArmHardFloatPort/VfpComparison
https://groups.google.com/group/nodejs-dev/browse_thread/thread/18bfc495b01e2f9b/8507143b5578ebf9#8507143b5578ebf9
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6788768/cannot-build-node-on-sheevaplug-armv5t-with-debian-squeeze/6790823#6790823
http://www.plugcomputer.org/plugwiki/index.php/Scratchbox2_based_cross_compiling
```

---

why 0.4.9, and not 0.6.6?
6.6 may be crapping out in same place but error says EABI error, compiler with Fonz doesn't understand EABI.

I think the V8 guys (or node guys) have relabelled the error descriptor to EABI, I don't know enough to trace problem.
There are heaps of other switches available for the compilers - I have given up trying them all (other people seem to have found the same problem, they are MUCH more knowledgable than I am, so I am going to assume that they have tried all the available switches that could make a difference).

### As a matter of interest the V8 compile only uses the CXXFLAGS switch to compile with, whilst the rest of NodeJS seems to use the others I have labelled!!

Also note that in order to get snapshot running it points to /tmp - no matter what I do, -
I ended up moving /tmp to /tmp1, and ln -s /tmp /ffp/tmp
ie

mv /tmp /tmp1

ln -s /tmp /ffp/tmp

---